# Как правильно написать тест PhpUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

Начал только изучать PhpUnit,и сразу попал в ступор.
Нужно в тесте создать тестовый объект,конструктор которого выглядит следующим образом

```
private $url;


    /**
     * ShowReport constructor.
     * @param GetFilename $url
     */
    public function __construct(GetFilename $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

    }
```

Как правильно создать подставной обЪект или какую то заглушку, чтобы можно было протестить класс. Смущает контроль типа в конструкторе

Comment: Это невозможно протестировать. Доступа к private properties нет. Да и не нужно. Вам надо тестировать функционал, а там однозначно вылезет этот самый $this->url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937845/mock-private-method-with-phpunit

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказку.
Нашел такое решение

```
$this->getFileMock=$this->createMock(GetFilename::class);
$this->getFileMock->method('getFileName')->willReturn('php.net');
$this->file=new ShowReport($this->getFileMock);
```

Comment: Надеюсь вы кроме того что нашли решение, прочувствовали всю прелесть моков :)